# Show second value from select option

Tags: html, html-select

I want show in input text from select option where in value have 2 data

```js
function changeHiddenInput (objDropDown)
{
    
   document.getElementById("hiddenInput").value = objDropDown.value; 
  
}
```

```html
<form name="ff">
     <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">
     <option value="j.hotmail.com|3">Jens</option>
     <option value="a.hotmail.com|4">Adam</option>
     <option value="d.homtail.com|5">Dan</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" id="hiddenInput" />
</form>
```

I want get value 3,4,5 and show in input text form when each option select.

Answer (score 2):

split your value using " | "

```js
function changeHiddenInput (objDropDown)
{
    
   document.getElementById("hiddenInput").value = objDropDown.value.split('|')[1]; 
  
}
```

```html
<form name="ff">
     <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">
     <option value="j.hotmail.com|3">Jens</option>
     <option value="a.hotmail.com|4">Adam</option>
     <option value="d.homtail.com|5">Dan</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" id="hiddenInput" />
</form>
```

Comment: great! remember you can mark the answer as correct, to help others